# CompareTo - alphabetical order [Java Applet]

Tags: java, applet, compareto, alphabetical-sort

I would like to sort the data from TextField to the TextArea, 
but i don't have no idea how to finish code.

I know that this simple but just getting started with java.

```
package abcorder;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sort extends Applet
{
Button b1;
TextField t1, t2;
TextArea t3;
String result;

public void init()
{
    b1 = new Button("Send");
    t1 = new TextField(10);
    t2 = new TextField(10);
    t3 = new TextArea(8, 25);

    this.add(t1);
    this.add(t2);
    this.add(b1);
    this.add(t3);
}

private boolean sort(String s1, String s2)
{
    if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}


public boolean action(Event e, Object o)
{
    String s1, s2;
    s1 = new String(t1.getText());
    s2 = new String(t2.getText());

    if (e.target == b1)
    {   
        t3.append(result);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

I can't figure it out and am stuck.
Thanks ;)

Comment: And your question/problem is...

Comment: You have a sort method that you dont call anywhere, so even if it was correct, wouldnt do you much good. Also, you should read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/#sorting

Comment: How call sort method ?